# Testing AbstractProcessor (Java's annotation handling at compile time)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, annotations, preprocessor

I am writing a library which relies on the `AbstractProcessor` class, since I want to write a great library I want to have a good coverage too. Since the *preprocessor* works at the compile time I am not sure how to test that code.

I have some test scenarios in mind where the build should fail. However how can I test that? Do I have to execute gradle and check the exit code? Is there a clean way to verify that the build fails caused by an expected cause or do I need to write also some kind of parser? That would be IMHO a huge overhead just for a good coverage.

For those of you which need a example:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("eu.rekisoft.java.preprocessor.Decorator")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class ExamplePreprocessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public ExamplePreprocessor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for(Element elem : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Decorator.class)) {
            Method method = Method.from((ExecutableElement)elem);
            if(!method.matchesTypes(String.class, StringBuilder.class)) {
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "No! " + elem + " has the wrong args!");
            } else {
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Yey " + elem + " this is fine!");
            }
        }
        return true; // no further processing of this annotation type
    }
}
```

And here is a class which cannot been compiled:

```
public class AnnotationedExample {
    @Decorator
    public int breakBuild() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Decorator
    public String willCompile(StringBuilder sb) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally the boring annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Decorator {
}
```

You can also checkout the project at [GitHub](https://github.com/rekire/AnnotationTesting) you just need to check out the project and execute `gradlew cJ`. You may have to fix the missing x permission on the script on linux and mac.

Comment: Please share your code and the test scenarios you have written so far. What is wrong with them?

Comment: Just wondering do you know what I am talking about? It is a high complex topic and if you are familar with it the abstract level of my question should be fine. However I can add an example if this makes it more clear for you.

Comment: @RobertColumbia here is a simple example project which cannot compile as intended: https://github.com/rekire/AnnotationTesting you just need to check out the project and execute `gradlew cJ`, if you use linux you have to fix the missing x permission of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by previous teams writing compilers and annotation processors, so you could re-use their solutions.

The javac team uses a tool called [jtreg](http://openjdk.java.net/jtreg/).
For example, here is a [jtreg test](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/checker/jtreg/multiplecheckers/NullnessInterning.java) that compiles a source file 6 times with different command-line arguments, indicating a different [expected compiler output](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/checker/jtreg/multiplecheckers/NullnessInterning2.out) for each one.

The [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) team designed a testing framework specifically for annotation processors.  Here is a [test case](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/checker/tests/nullness/generics/MethodTypeVars.java) using that framework, where special `//::` comments indicate the lines where the annotation processor is expected to issue [a warning](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/checker/tests/nullness/generics/MethodTypeVars.java#L21) or [an error](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/blob/master/checker/tests/nullness/generics/MethodTypeVars.java#L9).

Comment: I am trying to use that jtreg library however I do not really understand how to use it. I will try to tun jtreg within gradle and for now I know that I can run `java -Dprogram=jtreg -jar /tmp/jtreg/lib/jtreg.jar`, but what args do I need to apply? How does that `@Compile` comment start a new compile process? I do not get it at all.

Comment: Okay I guess I got it now managed, however my reference file does not match. How do I find out the exact format of the file? Just the expected error output?

Comment: Yes, jtreg requires the compiler output to match the goal file.  jtreg does not attempt to do clever parsing of the output.  For how to run jtreg, I suggest seeing the jtreg documentation.

Comment: Oh man I debugged now `CompileAction.compareGoldenFile(...)` I missed that I had a debug message in the output stream. So it does not just look at the error stream. Good to know!

Answer (score 4):

Google has a very good API for testing compilation. (https://github.com/google/compile-testing). Here's a example to test if a .java file compiles with a processor using junit.

```
package org.coffeebag.processor;

import com.google.testing.compile.JavaFileObjects;
import com.google.testing.compile.JavaSourceSubjectFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import static org.truth0.Truth.ASSERT;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void EmptyClassCompiles() throws MalformedURLException {
        final MyProcessor processor = MyProcessor.testMode();
        File source = new File("path/to/test/file.java");
        ASSERT.about(JavaSourceSubjectFactory.javaSource())
                .that(JavaFileObjects.forResource(source.toURI().toURL()))
                .processedWith(processor)
                .compilesWithoutError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've written a simplified API that helps access the `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` API for in-memory Java compilation, which allows for writing simple JUnit based test. In your example, you could write:

```
@Test
public void testFailAnnotationProcessing() {
    ExamplePreprocessor p = new ExamplePreprocessor();
    try {
        Reflect.compile(
            "com.example.test.FailAnnotationProcessing",
            "package com.example.test; " +
            "public class FailAnnotationProcessing { " +
            "    @com.example.Decorator " +
            "    public int breakBuild() { " +
            "        return -1; " +
            "    } " +
            "}",
            new CompileOptions().processors(p)
        ).create().get();
        Assert.fail();
    }
    catch (ReflectException expected) {}
}

@Test
public void testSucceedAnnotationProcessing() {
    ExamplePreprocessor p = new ExamplePreprocessor();
    Reflect.compile(
        "com.example.test.SucceedAnnotationProcessing",
        "package com.example.test; " +
        "public class SucceedAnnotationProcessing { " +
        "    @com.example.Decorator " +
        "    public String willCompile(StringBuilder sb) { " +
        "        return null; " +
        "    } " +
        "}",
        new CompileOptions().processors(p)
    ).create().get();
}
```

[More examples can be seen here](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/12/07/how-to-unit-test-your-annotation-processor-using-joor/).